# postgres initialize with git

Tags: postgresql, git, docker-compose

I'm using postgres with docker and git

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres: 12.7
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxx
```

tree

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── data
    └── .gitignore
```

I need a gitignore file to add folder to repository([how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)),
but postgres will raise an error because of non-empty folder

```
initdb: error: directory "/var/lib/postgres/data" exists but is not empty
```

Is there any solution for this?

I've try to run a script to clear gitignore file before postgres launched, but I failed to run it in commands

```
gitignore=$PGDATA/.gitignore
git_keep=$PGDATA/.gitkeep
if [ -f "$gitignore" ] ; then
    rm "$gitignore"
fi
if [ -f "$git_keep" ] ; then
    rm "$git_keep"
fi
```

Comment: Can you move the gitignore file to top directory as docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: The .gitignore exists because  empty directories can't be tracked by git (git only tracks files).  It won't have the same effect if not in that directory.  I was going to suggest yesterday having a makefile / readme instructions for the one-time operation of creating that directory, or using a volume maybe?  I didn't like those solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found a solution that worked for me by using `PGDATA`. By tracking the `data/` folder on GitHub and ignoring everything inside it I can let postgres use a sub directory to store data using the `PGDATA` environment variable. Since this does not need to be mounted by docker this can stay untracked and postgres will auto generate data to this folder. This makes it possible for anyone cloning the git repo to start the docker container without having to create a directory

With this compose file:

```yaml
  postgres-local:
    hostname: local-postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    # mounts my data which is tracked on GitHub
    volumes:
      - ../database/data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pwd
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
      - PGPORT=5434
      # this is not tracked and will be auto generated by postgres
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/
    ports:
      - 5434:5434
```

Then the structure looks like this:

```
database/
 - data
   # ignores pgdata 
   - .gitignore
```